# Can't boot from pendrive

Tags: boot, boot-repair, grub-efi

Recently i've been trying to format my computer from Ubuntu 16.04LTS to Windows. I've already made the booting pendrive with Windows inside, but when i try booting from it, i get the following message:

```
Failed to open \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\grubx64.efi - Not Found
Failed to load image \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\grubx64.efi: Not Found
start_image() returned Not Found
```

I've used **Boot Repair** recently.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Did you format the drive to make it bootable? Using `dd` or Rufus or unetbootin?

Comment: I tried using a clean CD, formatting by the GUI and by unetbootin.

Comment: I thought you were using a flash drive? Or did you try both?

Comment: I tried CD once, and pen-drive 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

Those messages come from Shim (`shimx64.efi`); in your case, it's likely in the `EFI/Microsoft/Boot` directory on the [EFI System Partition (ESP).](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) They likely indicate that you used an advanced Boot Repair option (called "back up and rename boot loaders" or something similar) to put GRUB (and Shim) in the position normally used by the Windows boot loader; however, something has gone wrong -- either GRUB (`grubx64.efi`) has subsequently been deleted or there's been filesystem damage that's causing Shim to be unable to read GRUB. Even if GRUB were to load, if you've already deleted the Ubuntu partition, you'd probably get a `grub>` prompt and be unable to boot Windows -- at least, not without fairly esoteric knowledge of how to use GRUB at its command line and where the Windows boot loader has gone.

You have two main courses of action at this point:

- **Undo what Boot Repair did** -- If you used the Boot Repair option to back up and rename boot loaders, the same program offers a way to reverse that action. You could use that option to (theoretically) restore the system to bootability. There is the caveat, though, that whatever is causing Shim to be unable to find GRUB might complicate this process. In fact, there's a chance that you'd make matters worse -- but in this case, the solution would be the same as the alternative solution at your current point, so that might not really be such a big deal....
- **Use Windows boot recovery procedures** -- Windows provides boot recovery procedures that you can use in this type of situation. Basically, using a Windows emergency disk or the recovery tool on your hard disk, you'd use automatic tools or issue special commands to re-write the Windows boot loader to the ESP. I lack the Windows expertise to provide better guidance on this, though; and as this is a Windows recovery procedure, you're better off asking about it on a Windows forum, in any event.

Note that filesystem damage to the ESP can be caused by a failure to disable the Windows [Fast Startup](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-10-a.html) and [Hibernate](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2859-hibernate-enable-disable-windows-10-a.html) features. Disabling these features is a *requirement* for safe dual-booting between Windows 8 or later and any other OS, including Ubuntu. If you decide to try a dual boot again, be sure to disable those features, as described on the pages to which I've linked.